# Node.js mysql query passing to next function in async.waterfall

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I have some code in node.js using express. I route a call to request data from a mysql database, and what I want to do is pass that to another function to restructure the returned json from a tabular form (table query) to a hierarchy type json.

I've tested the script separately to restructure the output from my sql query. However, I am having trouble passing it from my query function to my new script(function)

I'm just not seeing what I am doing wrong. Any help please and thanks.

```
exports.get_site_menu = function (req, res) {
    var dbc;
    console.log('In menu setup');
    async.waterfall([
        // get a connection

        function (callback) {
            db.db(callback);
        }

        ,
        querylookup, modifyjson
    ], completed);

    function querylookup(dbclient, res) {
        dbc = dbclient;
        dbc.query("SELECT categories, " +
            "subcategories, " +
            "pid, " +
            "title, " +
            "description " +
            "FROM MENU_SELECT_ACTIVE_VIEW " +
            "where company_id = ? and site_id = ?", [req.query.companyid, req.query.siteid], res);
    }

    function modifyjson(err, res) {

        categories = [];

        console.log('results ' + res);

        res.forEach(function (entry) {
            var cindex = categories.map(function (category) {
                return category.name;
            }).indexOf(entry.categories);

            console.log(cindex);
            if (cindex < 0) {
                // Not found in categories array
                cindex = categories.push({
                    name: entry.categories,
                    subcategories: []
                }) - 1; // -1 to fix the index
            }
            // Lets search the subcategory
            var category = categories[cindex];

            var sindex = category.subcategories.map(
                function (subcategory) {
                    return subcategory.name;
                }
            ).indexOf(entry.subcategories);

            if (sindex < 0) {
                // Not Found
                sindex = category.subcategories.push({
                    name: entry.subcategories,
                    items: []
                }) - 1;
            }
            // Subcategory exists. Just push
            category.subcategories[sindex].items.push({
                pid: entry.pid,
                description: entry.description,
                title: entry.title
            });
        });

        menu = {
            menu: {
                categories: categories
            }
        };
        console.log('menu ' + menu);
    }


    function completed(err, menu, fields) {
        if (dbc) dbc.end();
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log(menu);
            res.contentType('json');
            res.send(JSON.stringify(menu));
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass each result to own callback to pass next function. I have refactored your code like;

```
exports.get_site_menu = function (req, res) {
    var dbc;
    console.log('In menu setup');
    async.waterfall([
        // get a connection

        function (callback) {
            db.db(callback, some_result);
        },
        function querylookup(dbclient, res, callback) {
            dbc = dbclient;
            dbc.query("SELECT categories, " +
                "subcategories, " +
                "pid, " +
                "title, " +
                "description " +
                "FROM MENU_SELECT_ACTIVE_VIEW " +
                "where company_id = ? and site_id = ?", [req.query.companyid, req.query.siteid], res);
                callback(null, result_from_queryLookup);
        },
        function modifyjson(err, res, callback) {

            categories = [];

            console.log('results ' + res);

            res.forEach(function (entry) {
                var cindex = categories.map(function (category) {
                    return category.name;
                }).indexOf(entry.categories);

                console.log(cindex);
                if (cindex < 0) {
                    // Not found in categories array
                    cindex = categories.push({
                        name: entry.categories,
                        subcategories: []
                    }) - 1; // -1 to fix the index
                }
                // Lets search the subcategory
                var category = categories[cindex];

                var sindex = category.subcategories.map(
                    function (subcategory) {
                        return subcategory.name;
                    }
                ).indexOf(entry.subcategories);

                if (sindex < 0) {
                    // Not Found
                    sindex = category.subcategories.push({
                        name: entry.subcategories,
                        items: []
                    }) - 1;
                }
                // Subcategory exists. Just push
                category.subcategories[sindex].items.push({
                    pid: entry.pid,
                    description: entry.description,
                    title: entry.title
                });
            });

            menu = {
                menu: {
                    categories: categories
                }
            };
            console.log('menu ' + menu);
            callback(null, menu, fields);
        }
    ], function completed(err, menu, fields) {
        if (dbc) dbc.end();
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log(menu);
            res.contentType('json');
            res.send(JSON.stringify(menu));
        }
    });
};
```

Especially, be careful on callback parts.

Comment: hmmm ok I see what you mean...

I get this error now

db.db(callback, some_result);
                            ^
ReferenceError: some_result is not defined
    at async.waterfall.dbc (/Users/dpreston10/Dropbox/workspace/QwikAssistServer/data/getdata.js:119:29)
    at fn    (/Users/dpreston10/Dropbox/workspace/QwikAssistServer/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:517:34)
    at          /Users/dpreston10/Dropbox/workspace/QwikAssistServer/node_modules/async/li    b/async.js:441:34
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

Comment: some_result is my temp variable. You need to replace it with your own. I assume, first function generates a value called some_result and I passed it to second function, and so on

Comment: Im sorry :-(  I'm just not getting past it. My result from the query are not passing down no matter what variables I use. The only variables passed into the first function are the 2 inputs for the query.

Comment: However, waterfall does not work that way. You need to pass step by step down the functions